# GitHub Pages用とpull request用にふたつforkしたい

Tags: github, github-pages

https://github.com/Drassil/git-wiki という GitHub Pages / Jekyll 用のテンプレートで遊ぶために、一度リポジトリを自分の GitHub アカウントで fork し nekketsuuu/git-wiki-sandbox という名前を付けました。

暫く遊んだ後、Drassil/git-wiki に pull request を送りたくなったのでそのためのリポジトリとして再び fork し nekketsuuu/git-wiki を作りたくなったのですが、GitHub では同じリポジトリを同じアカウントで二度 fork することができません。nekketsuuu/git-wiki-sandbox はそれ自体が別個の GitHub Pages として使われているため、pull request を送るための branch を nekketsuuu/git-wiki-sandbox に作るのは違和感があります。

このような場合、どのように対応すれば良いのでしょうか？　最初に fork したのが間違いで、単なるリポジトリコピーにすべきだったのでしょうか。

<sub>補足：実際に Drassil/git-wiki を fork しようとした際に出るメッセージ。</sub>

[image: "You've already forked git-wiki" と表示されています。]

Comment: 自分自身にオーナー権限があるもの = fork済みリポジトリからはforkできませんが、元リポジトリを開けば再度forkを実行できませんか？ (forkボタンにマウスオーバーすると説明が表示されるはず)

Comment: @cubick さん、できませんでした。スクリーンショットを添付したのでご覧ください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

プルリクエストを送るつもりのリポジトリはforkで作成しておく必要がありそうですが、単にupstreamとして参照するだけであればGitHub上で空のリポジトリを作成しておき、ローカルに予めコピーしておいたデータをpushすればよさそうです。

```
$ git clone https://github.com/USER/ORIGIN.git
$ git remote rename origin upstream

... GitHub 上で MyRepo を作成しておく

$ git remote add origin https://github/USER/MyRepo.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

参考:
[Create Multiple Forks of a GitHub Repo](https://handong1587.github.io/linux_study/2015/12/18/create-multi-forks.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます！　おそらく殆ど同等の機能があるであろう [GitHub Importer を使うことによって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/61906/19110)良い感じのコピーを作ることができました。fork リポジトリを削除すれば再度 fork できることも確認しました。

Comment: 今回の場合もとのリポジトリがテンプレートとして公開されているので、もし最初から気付けていれば手動コピーや import の他に「[テンプレートからリポジトリを作成する](https://help.github.com/ja/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-from-a-template)」を選ぶという選択肢もあったようです。