# コミット履歴などを保持しつつfork関係だけを無くすようにリポジトリをコピーしたい

Tags: git, github

GitHub で一度 fork したリポジトリを fork ではなくコピーにしたいです（[経緯](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61893/19110)）。この際、コミット履歴などは保持しつつ、fork したということだけを無くすようにしたいです。どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

手動で git コマンドを叩いてコピーすることも[できます](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41486339/5989200)が、GitHub の機能を使ってコピーするのが便利です。

[image: プラスボタンを押して出てきたメニューの中に、Import repositoryの文字があります]

1. サイト右上の `+` ボタンを押す。
2. ["Import repository"](https://github.com/new/import) を選択する。
3. 古いリポジトリの URL をコピー＆ペーストし、新しいリポジトリ名を入力する。
4. "Begin import" ボタンを押す。

なお注意点として（現状）issue 等はコピーされません。

公式ヘルプ：[GitHub にソースコードをインポートする](https://help.github.com/ja/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github)